# Why does DataFrame row selection syntax df[:2] work but not if the syntax df[1]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have following data:

`data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), index = ['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Utah', 'New York'], columns = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])`

If I run:
`data[:2]`
the output will be:

```
           one  two three four
Ohio        0    1    2   3
Colorado    4    5    6   7
```

If I run: `data[1]`, the following error will show up:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-c402bf503b75> in <module>
----> 1 data[1]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1
```

Why could I run `data[:2]` but not `data[1]`? It doesn't make sense to me. Thank you in advance:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[ ]` - indexing operator looks for a column name entered.

In your example `data[1]`, there is no column by name `1`. So the key error.

But, when you pass slicing notation `:` inside the indexing operator, the indexing operator changes the behavior from ***"searching for columns"*** to ***"searching for rows based on the range"***

Answer (score 1):

The first portion `data[:1]` is a slicing operation. and As you set the `index = ['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'Utah', 'New York']` so there is no default index (0-9..) that's why it gives you a key error.

if you enter the column name. like `data['one']` you will get

Ohio         0

Colorado     4

Utah         8

New York    12

Name:    one, dtype: int64